# C99 shorthand for operations on fields of a single struct variable?

Tags: c, struct

Let's say I have this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct foo {
  int bar;
  int baz;
  double qux;
} foo_t;

foo_t my_foo = {
  .bar = 0,
  .baz = 0,
  .qux = 0,
};

int main() {
  my_foo.bar = 100;
  my_foo.baz = my_foo.bar/2 + 4;
  my_foo.qux = my_foo.bar/3.0 + my_foo.baz/5.0;
  printf("Hello, world %f!", my_foo.qux);
  return 0;
}
```

Above, I'm using the "designated initializer style" `{ .bar = 0, ...}` to initilize the struct variable, which I consider a kind of a shorthand.

I was wondering - is there some shorthand syntax, that would also allow for operations on fields of the same struct variable? For instance, instead of writing:

```
  my_foo.bar = 100;
  my_foo.baz = my_foo.bar/2 + 4;
  my_foo.qux = my_foo.bar/3.0 + my_foo.baz/5.0;
```

... I could imagine a shorthand syntax like this (below pseudocode somewhat inspired by Python):

```
with(my_foo) {
  .bar = 100;
  .baz = .bar/2 + 4;
  .qux = .bar/3.0 + .baz/5.0;
}
```

Is there something like this in C (C99, to be more specific)?

Comment: No, there is no such thing.

Comment: You could try using `foo_t foo = { .bar = 100, .bax = foo.bar + 10 };`. However, the order of evaluation of initializers is **unspecified** so this may fail unexpectedly. On the other side, I expect this to work fine because C++ forces specific evaluation order and C and C++ compilers share quite a lot of code.

Comment: C has no "this" object like C++ and other languages with OO support. So it has no way to tell which object you are currently working on, you have to tell it explicitly.

Comment: @Lundin, AFAIK, very popular OO language known as Python has no "this" as well

Comment: @tstanisl Sure that is unspecified?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I think it is unspecified. See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p23 . Am I wrong?

Comment: @tstanisl Looks like you are [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71453481/2410359).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C has no such syntax.  You need to specify the struct variable followed by the member name.

The closest you can come to this is to create pointers to each member and work with those.

```
int *bar = &foo.bar;
int *baz = &foo.baz;
double *qux = &foo.qux;
*bar = 100;
*baz = *bar/2 + 4;
*qux = *bar/3.0 + *baz/5.0;
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm accepting this answer, mostly because of the explicit mention of "no such syntax"; even though I like the suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use the KISS principle. Meaning stick to simple, existing features in order to create readable, maintainable code:

```
void fooify (foo_t* dst, const foo_t* src)
{
  int bar = src->bar;    
  int baz = src->baz;
  double qux = src->qux;

  bar += 100;
  baz = bar/2 + 4;
  qux = bar/3.0 + baz/5.0;

  *dst = (foo_t) 
  {
    .bar = bar,
    .baz = baz,
    .qux = qux,
  };
}
```